# AES CBC with mysql and Python

Tags: encryption, aes, mysql, python

I'm writing a little program that stores passwords in Python. I access to the DB with `Mysqldb` module.
I want to encrypt the password with `AES 256 with CBC`. I'm trying to do this with SQL [`AES_ENCRYPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) function.

I set the cbc mode with: 
`mysql> SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';`

So in python, I have:

```
def add_password(self, table, site, password, key, iv):
        try:
            query = "INSERT INTO " +table+ " (sites, password) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT(%s, %s, %s), AES_ENCRYPT(%s,%s,%s) )"
            self.cursor.execute(query, ( site, key, iv, password, key, iv))
            self.conn.commit()
        ...
```

But, if a run the program I get:
`Warning: <IV> option ignored`, as if the function uses ECB mode (so without iv).

Where I wrong?

Possible way:
Or is it better encrypt all with python modules and the insert into the DB the data already encrypted?

**EDIT**

Seems that if I add every time `SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc'`, all woks.

```
def add_password(self, table, site, password, key,iv):
        try:
            query = "SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc'"
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            query = "INSERT INTO " +table+ " (sites, password) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT(%s, %s, %s), AES_ENCRYPT(%s,%s,%s) )"
            self.cursor.execute(query, ( site, key,iv, password, key, iv))
            self.conn.commit()
            ...
```

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-system-variables.html. The way you’ve just edited in is a fine way to set the variable. (I’d have Python do the encryption, though.)